# How to Use Loop in R to Count Frequency of an Occurrence?

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, while-loop

Essentially, I have a data set containing many people and a classification. A snippet:

[image: Table 1]

I'd like to use a loop in R to iterate over the classification column to print out a frequency table which looks like this:

[image: Table 2]

How could I do something like that? As an example for classification A: I'd like to loop through all 'A' classifications for an individual and then count the frequency that they appear for that person, which is printed in a new vector.

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

We can use `count`

```
library(dplyr)
count(df1, Classification, Person)
```

Comment: True, and that does yield the result! But I'm curious - how would you use a loop to go beyond this to determine which person had the highest frequency of A classifications, B classifications, etc.? @akrun

Comment: @HelpNeeded FOr the second question, you just need `count(df1, Classification, Person) %>% slice_max(n)`

Comment: @HelpNeeded Can you use dput to show an example for testing. thanks

Comment: Thanks for the help - but using %>% slice_max(n) only returns one value which is the person with the highest n overall. What I'd like ideally is the highest n printed for each classification. E.g. a list with A = 2 (if 2 was the max frequency), B = 1 (if 1 was the max frequency), etc. Does that make sense? Could a loop achieve this? @akrun